# How to observe (monitor) a channel

Tags: go

Is it possible to get copy of channel messages? (instead of receive and delete message from channel)

The idea is to log a channel's messages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible to get copy of channel messages?

No.

Answer (score 3):

No, this is not possible, but you can use two channels, and pass between them observing the data in transit:

```golang
func observe(ch interface{}) ch interface{} {
    newCh := make(chan interface{})
    go func() {
        for item := range ch {
            fmt.Println(item)
            newCh <- item
        }
        close(newCh)
    }()
    return newCh
}
```

Comment: That's creative. But that will add buffer to unbuffered channels

Comment: No, it does not add any buffer. It might effectively remove one (as in this example), though.  It definitely changes the nature of buffered channels, so if you're using a buffered channel, you probably want the input channel to be unbuffered, and move the buffering only to the output channel.

Comment: you are right. there is only 1 step between these two channels. Thanks a lot